# Can't get mouse callback to work with java swing

Tags: java, swing, matlab

I would like to get eventData when the mouse is clicked or dragged along a slider. I have tried suggestions across blog posts (http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks) and the corresponding book. It seems to me that I am missing something.  Here is the code:

```
function testMouse
hFig = figure('Position',[450 100 700 850]);

jSlider = javax.swing.JSlider;
[jSlider,~] = javacomponent(jSlider,[100,20,500,50]);
jbh = handle(jSlider,'CallbackProperties');

set (jbh, 'MouseDraggedCallbackData', @myCallbackFcn)

guidata(hFig, handles);

function myCallbackFcn
get (jbh, 'MouseDraggedCallbackData')
guidata(hFig, handles);
```

Here is the error I get when I run the code in MATLAB:

Error using javahandle_withcallbacks.javax.swing.JSlider/set
Changing the 'MouseDraggedCallbackData' property of javahandle_withcallbacks.javax.swing.JSlider is not allowed.

Error in testMouse (line 8)
set (jbh, 'MouseDraggedCallbackData', @myCallbackFcn)

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Not sure about how to handle swing from Matlab, but I am surprised to see that the event you listen to is `MouseDragged`. Normally this event belongs to a `MouseListener`. Maybe try changing the event to `StateChanged`, as it is the standard event to monitor `JSlider` changes, as demonstrated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html).

Comment: Thanks @EricLeibenguth. I took a look at the page, but I am not sure how to implement that code in Matlab.

Comment: Maybe just see what happens when you replace `MouseDraggedCallbackData` with `StateChangedCallbackData`

Comment: Looks like there is more to it than that. Similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my colleague for sharing a simple way to get the final value from the slider. Here is the code:

```
function jSlider = testMouse2

hFig = figure('Position',[450 100 700 850]);

jSlider = javax.swing.JSlider;
jSlider.setMinimum(0);
jSlider.setMaximum(20);
jSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
jSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
jSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
jSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
jSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
javacomponent(jSlider,[10,70,600,45]);

end
```

You can call the function, and then simply use a java call to get the final value of the slider this way:

```
slider = testMouse2;

slider.getValue
```